# Object by reference and without reference

Tags: c++

I want to ask one simple question which is making me confuse.
for example if I write in argument there is no reference &. but in the second case I have used & with rectangleType&, I am having confusion why we use this & when we can do it without this &. Where is this necessary and why we use it. My question is not about copy constructor.

```
 rectangleType rectangleType::operator+
(const rectangleType rectangle)
```

Case 2:

```
rectangleType rectangleType::operator+
(const rectangleType& rectangle)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564873/reference-parameters-in-c-very-basic-example-please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object like `rectangleType` (or any other type) by value, you're making a copy of that object. This means:

- Any changes made to the object by the function are not seen by the caller, since the changes are made on a copy, not the original object.
- The act of copying the object incurs a performance cost.
- Copying the object may not even be possible for some types.

So, pass by reference whenever:

- You want the function to be able to modify the original object.
- You want the code to run faster by not having to make a copy.
- The object you're passing doesn't have a public copy constructor.

Pass by *const* reference whenever you *don't* need the function to be able to modify the original object.

For user-defined types, this essentially boils down to "pass by reference wherever possible."

Comment: The OP asks about const references

Comment: @Paranaix No he didn't; `const` only appears in his example code, and from his question I suppose his confusion is more general than specifically regarding `const`. All the same I added a note about `const` to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How can you state that your question is not about copy construction if the answere is about it?

1. With a const reference no copy is made, this can be crucial for very large objects
2. There are classes wich explicitely dont provide a copy constructor, this way you can still pass them around.

So to conclude: You get benefits without disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, it will receive a (complete) instance of `rectangleType`, that will be created using the *copy constructor* just to be passed as a parameter.

In the second method, it will receive a reference to an already existing instance; no copy will be made.