# How do I pass data through multiple functions and call them correctly in main?

Tags: c++, function, scope, program-entry-point, type-conversion

I'm trying to call `userWeight` into the `double convert()` function. How do I do this? I'm running into issues with it no cooperating in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// health calc

string name()
{
    cout << "Welcome ________ ... uhmmmm, what was your name again?   ";
    string name1;
    cin >> name1;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Oh that's right! Your name was " << name1 << ", how could I forget that?!" << endl;
    return name1;

}

int height(string name1) //(string name1) is what we are passing into this function
{
    //feet and inches to inches
    cout << " How tall are you, " << name1 <<"?"<< endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Enter feet:    ";
    int feet;
    cin >> feet;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Enter inches:    ";
    int inches;
    cin >> inches;
    int inchesheight;

    inchesheight = (feet * 12) + inches;

    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Your height is equal to " << inchesheight << " inches total." << endl;


    if (inchesheight < 65 )
    {
        cout << " You are shorter than the average male." << endl;
    }
    else if (inchesheight > 66 && inchesheight < 72)
    {
        cout << " You are of average height." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " You are taller than average." << endl;
    }


}

double wieght()
{
    cout << " How much do you weigh? (In pounds) " << endl;
    double userWeight;
    cin >> userWeight;

    cout << " Ok so your weight in the Imperial System (lbs.), is " << userWeight << endl;
    cout << " Would you like to know what your weight is in the Metric System? (kilograms) " << endl;
cout << " please answer as 'yes' or 'no;" << endl;
string response;
cin >> response;

    if (response == "yes")
    {
        cout << " Alright! Let us start converting your weight! " << endl;
    }
    else if (response == "no")
    {
        cout << " Too bad! We are going to do it anyway! " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " That was not a proper response! Way to follow directions!, as consequence, we will do it!" << endl;
    }

    return userWeight;


}

double convert(double userWeight)
{
    cout << " Well since 1 kilogram is equal to 2.2046226218 pounds, we need to divide your weight by that repeating number." << endl;
    cout << " Since that number is very long and ugly, we will use 2.2046 for the sake of clarity." << endl;
    double kiloWeight = (userWeight / 2.2046);
    cout << "Your weight in pounds is " << userWeight << "lbs, divided by 2.2046 gives us" << kiloWeight << "kgs! " << endl;


}


int main()
{

    string name1 = name();
    height(name1);
    weight(userWeight);
    convert();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh, "function parameters"?  Look here: [Reference Parameters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564873/reference-parameters-in-c-very-basic-example-please).  [Function returns](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c12.htm) are another option.  [Global variables](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node19.html) are another (but generally poor) choice.

Comment: You also have a typo: `double wieght()`.

Comment: You should either a) switch the tutorial you're doing, b) read further in your tutorial or c) buy a book about c++.

Comment: tough crowd here on stack

Comment: Sorry, it's not meant in a negative way, but this questions should be covered on the first pages of every book or tutorial. You'll learn a lot faster reading a comprehensive guide than asking a lot of basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should read about function signature and passing arguments.

You have defined `weight` as a function that doesn't take any arguments

```
double weight() { //...}
```

but you are calling it with some parameter `userWeight` in main function

```
weight(userWeight);
```

and this parameter in addition is not defined. ( And no: you cannot call a function with argument being local argument on the stack of function being called from same scope - it is technically possible but this is not what you want).

This should be something like:

```
int main() {

    double userWeight = weight();
    double result = convert( userWeight);
    // we can see here that local variable named userWeight was assigned value 
    // from a call to weight() and this result is now being passed to convert
    // now you can use a result from calling convert
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ..what exactly should I do? I'm confused now.

Comment: userWeight is from the user already in the weight function. I'm trying to take this variable along with their input and carry the exact same thing into the convert function.

Comment: All the work is being done in the functions and I just want main to subsequently run each function

Comment: the variable put on stack in weight() with double userWeight; cannot be accessed in another function

Comment: each call to a function creates a new stack and all variables that have been put on this are destroyed as function returns

Comment: So I can not keep carrying the same value from 'userWeight' throughout the program? I only want it in the next function. I was able to carry a string from one function to another, why can't I do this?!

Comment: You can, if you return value from function to local value to main, then pass this to another function: look at my example

Comment: @Appleshell double userWeight is not passed to weight but created in it

Comment: @bits_international Oh right, I was distracted by the code in the question. Misread the comment, sorry.

Comment: what exactly is result here?

Comment: what then has to be in the parameters of the convert function?

Comment: @user3719967 you can see it in my answer

Comment: not sure what you mean, but what goes in the parameter os the convert function now?

Comment: double userWeight = weight();
    double result = convert( userWeight); we can see here that local variable named userWeight was assigned value from calling of weight() and this result is now being passed to convert

Comment: alright but userWeight does not work in the convert function because it is not declared in that scope (error I got)

`double convert()` has no arguments in the parameters, is that why?

Comment: look, convert is declared as "double convert( double something)' and I call it in my answer with "convert( userWeight);"

Comment: I'm talking about the function OUTSIDE of main, tak a look at my code

Comment: even if `userWeight` is in those parameters, I stil legt the error that it is not declared in that scope

Comment: yes, your code is not correct, you should change it taking into account my hints. Delete a body of functions, just play with passing parameters first

Comment: i'm confused. is there no way you can just tell me exactly what's wrong? there is no one I'm going to get this now. I kept tweaking this to what you were saying and nothing

Comment: I was not giving the datatype of userWeight within the parameters of `double convert` ... that was my issue.. the code ran