# what does the *& mean in :void setData(const Color * & data_ptr);

Tags: c++, methods, colors, ppm

This is probably a dumb question but since i am new to programming and especially c++ i figured i would ask here.I have the following method inside a class:

```
/*! Copies the image data from an external raw buffer to
 *  the internal image buffer.
 *
 *  The member function ASSUMES that the input buffer is of a size compatible
 *  with the internal storage of the Image object and that the data buffer has
 *  been already allocated. If the image buffer is not allocated or the
 *  width or height of the image are 0, the method should exit immediately.
 *
 *  \param data_ptr is the reference to the preallocated buffer from where to
 *  copy the data to the Image object.
 */
void setData(const Color * & data_ptr);
```

Does the * & mean anything special? I know Color* is obviously a pointer but im having trouble with this. The external raw buffer mentioned in the comments of the code is a float array and the internal image buffer is a Color* buffer(Color is another class inside the same namespace).

Edit:Wow thanks for all the downvotes! Its not like i mentioned im at a beginner level and just now starting to  get into the language. Got to love the stackoverflow community. You make learning so fun!

Comment: `&` denotes a reference. `const Color * & data_ptr` means `data_ptr` is a reference to a `const Color *`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Reference Parameters in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564873/how-do-i-use-reference-parameters-in-c)

Comment: `Color*` is a pointer, and `&` in type definition means that it's a reference to a specified type. Hence - it's a reference to a pointer to a `Color`. Please read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4):

Read right to left: a reference to a pointer to `Color`.

That is, you are passing the pointer by reference, so that the function can change it. The `const` applies to Color, not to the pointer or the reference. I prefer writing the same as `Color const* & data_ptr`, so that you can read right-to-left and see what the `const` applies to.