# How can I pass a pointer to pointer to a function using the pointer it is pointing to?

Tags: c++, pointers

I made the following simplified code for the purpose of this question:

```
typedef struct {
int m;    // 
particle_t **inparticles;    // Pointers to particles pointers
} grid_t;

typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
} particle_t;

void apply_force( particle_t &particle, particle_t &neighbor , double *dmin, double *davg, int *navg)
{
    double dx = neighbor.x - particle.x; // do stuff ...
    double dy = neighbor.y - particle.y;
}

void apply_grid_force(particle_t &particle, grid_t &bin, double dmin, double davg, int navg)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < bin.m; j++) {
        apply_force(particle, bin.inparticles[j], &dmin, &davg, &navg);
    }
}
// error here: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘particle_t&’ from an rvalue of type ‘particle_t*’

int main()
{
    particle_t *particles = (particle_t*) malloc( 10 * sizeof(particle_t) ); // memory for particles pointers
    grid_t *grid = (grid_t*) malloc( 5 * sizeof(grid_t) ); // memory for grid pointers
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_bins; i++) {
        grid[i].inparticles = (particle_t**) malloc(3 * sizeof(particle_t *)); // memory for pointers to particles pointers
        grid[i].m = 0; 
    }
    
    apply_grid_force(grid[i].inparticles[j], grid[i], dmin, davg, navg);
// error here: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘particle_t&’ from expression of type ‘particle_t*’
}
```

How can I pass the poniter to pointer "inparticles" to the function apply_grid_force so I can use the "particle" it is pointing to?

If I am not mistaken the problem is arising from me trying to cast the double-pointer to a pointer (inparticles to particles) but I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Please do not use `typedef struct` in C++, it creates problems and solve none.

Comment: `malloc` -- Looks like you're writing C code, not C++.  Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: I apologize for the C and C++ code Frankenstein monster. I am only editing part of the code and that's what I am working with.

Comment: "If I am not mistaken the problem is arising from me trying...". Unfortunately looks like problem is arising from you not understanding what you are doing. You mix pointers with refernces left and right so it is difficult to say what is where. You better be consistent.

Comment: @Slava could you please provide a source for "Please do not use typedef struct in C++"? I would like to learn more.

Comment: You are confusing pointers and references in `apply_force(&particle, bin.inparticles[j], &dmin, &davg, &navg);` where `void apply_force( particle_t &particle, ...` takes a *reference-to* `particle_t` yet you are attempting to pass the *address of* `particle` (e.g. `&particle`). That's apples and oranges.

Comment: @zois 1 unlike C in C++ `struct` name is a type, so using `typedef struct ...` is pointless. 2 - you cannot forward declare such name, so it create problems.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the term "double pointer". Use something like "pointer to pointer" instead. The problem is that "double pointer" can mean `double*`. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/double-pointer/info

Comment: @Slava granted, new code should not `typedef` structs (or classes), but depending on how old this legacy code is it may have originally been written that way in the 90s. For purposes here, so long as there is no reliance on a constructor, etc.. (which `malloc()` knows nothing about) it won't impact this particular question. But you are 100% correct as a general proposition. (the same applies to the use of `malloc()` in C++, it shouldn't be the allocation method used today, but for a decade plus of legacy code, you still find it in places)

Comment: @YaserBaqi -- Maybe the confusion is that `&` has two meanings in C++, and neither are related.  The first one is the classic `C` definition of `&` meaning `address-of`.  Then the second meaning is for C++, where `&` means reference.  You seem to be conflating the two meanings.

Comment: `apply_grid_force(grid[i].inparticles[j], grid[i], dmin, davg, navg);` is not within any loop, so the `i` and `j` subscripts make no sense. Please show your actual code.  [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As shown, you would need something like `void apply_grid_force (particle_t &particle, grid_t &bin, double dmin, double davg, int navg) {...}` that calls `apply_force (particle, bin.inparticles[j], &dmin, &davg, &navg);` and then your call in `main()` makes sense -- but as shown, no values are initialized in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to cast a pointer-to-pointer to a pointer, you are casting a pointer-to-a-struct into a struct. `inparticles` is of the type `particle_t**`, so its elements are of the type `particle_t*` (that's what you're passing to the function with `grid[i].inparticles[j]`, you're getting an element of the array.)

Here's the thing, `apply_grid_force` doesn't take a pointer to a particle, it takes a reference, which is different. References are used just like regular variables but aren't copied when passed to a function, so modifying a passed reference modifies the *original* copy, just like a pointer, except that unlike a pointer you treat it, in code, like you would any other `particle_t`. It also means you should pass a `particle_t` to `apply_grid_force`, not a `particle_t*`, by dereferencing it:

```
apply_grid_force(*grid[i].inparticles[j], grid[i], dmin, davg, navg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just dereference it will remove an error ? Like this:

```
apply_grid_force(*grid[i].inparticles[j], grid[i], dmin, davg, navg);
```

I also agree with comments related to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a confusion with pointers and object-oriented concepts.

I will answer your question in both C (not object oriented) and C++ (object oriented).

## C

To use it in the function:

```
void accessParticle(particle_t *particle)
{
    particle->x = 5; //"particle" is a pointer to a particle_t structure
}
```

To pass it to the function:

```
accessParticle(grids[0].inparticles[0]); //"inparticles" is de-referenced to a pointer
```

## C++

To use it in the function:

```
void accessParticle(particle_t &particle)
{
    particle.x = 5; //"particle" is an object-reference to a particle_t structure
}
```

To pass it to the function:

```
accessParticle(*(grids[0].inparticles[0])); //Read explanation bellow
```

Here, `inparticles` is first de-referenced to **a pointer to a `particle_t` structure**, which is then de-referenced to **a `particle_t` structure**. The whole structure **is not** copied since only the **object reference** of this structure is passed to the function. In this way, `particle` (inside the `accessParticle` function) makes reference to the same object instance.

Please read this to further clarify any doubts:

- [How do I use Reference Parameters in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564873/how-do-i-use-reference-parameters-in-c)