# I don't understand a part of the C++ code, can someone explain it?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

I was wondering if someone could explain why the  f2(a,a); is 13 13 and not 12 12?

Does this have something to do with the & sign, if so what does it mean?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1 (int a, int b){
 a = 12; b = 13;
}
void f2 (int& a, int& b){
a = 12; b = 13;
}


int main()
{
 int a = 10; int b = 11;
 f1(a,b);
 cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ';
 f2(a,b);
 cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ';
 f2(a,a);
 cout << a << ' ' << b;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you expected it to be `12 12`?

Comment: Because in void f2 a is 12, that is why i excpecte it to be 12

Comment: You pass in `a` to both the `a` and `b` variables of `f2`. These are passed by reference. When it does `a = 12` in the `f2` function, you are indeed changing the value of `a` from `main` to `12` as well; however, immediately after, it does `b=13`, where `b` is still the same variable as `a`. Note that the variables `a` and `b` inside `main` are NOT the same `a` and `b` inside `f2`.

Comment: Try reading [How do I use Reference Parameters in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564873/10077).

Answer (score 1):

In your call `f2(a, a)` both arguments refer to the same variable (`a`) (the ampersand means "reference") so that is all you are changing. The function first assign 12 to it, then you assign 13 to it - so that's the final value. The variable `b` in the `main` function is not changed by that function call and retains its value (13), so when you subsequently print `a` and `b` in `main`, you get 13 and 13.

Comment: Does having two parameter references that both refer to the same caller's argument have the potential for undefined behavior?  And if so, under what circumstances (and is this one of those circumstances)?

Comment: @Eljay I think it's only if the two parameters have different types that you get into UB land. But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void f2 (int& a, int& b){
a = 12; b = 13;
}
```

accepts its arguments by reference. So calling it like

```
f2(a,a);
```

the both parameters are references to the same object `a`.

At first this object was assigned with the value `12`

```
a = 12;
```

and then reassigned with the value `13`

```
b = 13;
```

So the resulting value of the referenced object `a` is `13`.

To make it more clear you can imagine the function call and its definition the following way (I will rename the parameters as a1 and b1 to avoid name collision)

```
f2(a,a);

// ...

void f2 ( /* int& a1, int& b1 */ ){
    int &a1 = a;
    a1 = 12; 
    
    int &b1 = a;  
    b1 = 13;
}
```

So the object `a` is being changed through the reference to it `a1` and `b1`.

That is you may declare several references to the same object and use the references in any order to change the referenced object. The object will contain the last value assigned to it through one of the references.

Pay attention to that before this call

```
f2(a,a);
```

there was the following call

```
f2(a,b);
```

that set the value of the variable `b` to `13`.

So this statement after the above two calls

```
cout << a << ' ' << b;
```

outputs

```
13 13
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `a` to `f2(a,a);` as both parameters you are doing so as a reference parameter and your code is executed sequentially. So `a` is first given the value 12 (the value assigned to formal parameter `a` in the function) and then the same variable is given the value 13 (the value assigned to formal parameter `b` in the function). The variable `b` in the `main` part of your program was is 13 after the function call `f2(a,b);`.